# Problem using a date Stream Parameters in an SQL Query in SPSS Modeler

Tags: sql, spss-modeler

I am new to SPSS, and currently use SPSS modeler v18

I declared properly 2 variables in the Stream Parameters
DateDebut and DateFin
(dates for beginning and end)

I coded the following query in a SQL node

```
select distinct
            *
from ADMIN.FAIT_ENTT_TICK_ENT_2015_
where 
      date("DATE_TICK") >= date('$P-DateDebut')
  and date("DATE_TICK") <= date('$P-DateFin')
```

and I does output an empty table

The values I fill for the parameters are

```
DataDebut=2019-01-01
DateFin=2019-01-10
```

And

```
select distinct
    date('$P-DateDebut') as A, *
from ADMIN.FAIT_ENTT_TICK_ENT_2015_
where 
      date("DATE_TICK") >= date('2019-01-01')
  and date("DATE_TICK") <= date('2019-01-10')
```

works fine...

Do you have any idea?

(my server is a Netezza one)

Many thanks,
Nicolas

Comment: Edit your post using code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test the exact scenario that you have as I do not have access to a Netezza (IBM PureDate) appliance. However, I do not immediately see any issues with your SQL query and how you have incorporated the stream parameters. Executing against an MS SQL Server, I get the correct results using a query like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM [dbo].[sampleTable]
 WHERE [sampleDate] = '$P-selected_date'
```

There are a couple of things that might trip you up here:

- Is the format of the dates in the database and the stream parameter the same?
- Are there actually any records in the database within the date range?

One thing that might help to identify the issue is to turn on the SQL messages in the log and review the SQL query that is generated from the source node. Please take the following steps:

1. From the menu, select `Tools | Stream Properties | Options ...`
2. From the menu on the left, select `Logging and Status`
3. Make sure that the options for `Display SQL in the messages log during stream execution` and `Reformat SQL for improved readability` are checked
4. Attached a table node directly to your source node and execute the table node
5. From the menu, select `Tools | Stream Properties | Messages ...`
   In the messages, you should now be able to find the SQL the was generated from the source node and executed in the database and this might show you if the generated SQL command is different from what you are expecting.